# Map specific element to array from array of codable classes

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

Gallery is the array of `ProviderGallery` in this below model. I am trying to fetch specific variable of ProviderGallery to array without using forloop. The below code i used for loop to fetch the desired element.

Model :

```
struct ProviderProfileData : Codable{
     let message : String?
    let gallery : [ProviderGallery]?
    
  }
    
    struct ProviderGallery : Codable {
        let id : Int?
        let file_name : String?
        let thumb : String?
        let mime_type : String?
        let duration : String?
        let size : String?
    }
```

JSONDecoder :

```
 do {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      let providerProfileDetails = try decoder.decode(ProviderProfileData.self, from: data)
      print("data \(providerProfileDetails)")

      // Here i am getting desired value into array using forloop 
      
          if let gallery = providerProfileDetails.data.gallery {
                    
                    var thumbArray = [String]()
                    
                    for i in 0..<gallery.count{
                        thumbArray.append(gallery[i].thumb ?? "")
                    }
                    print("thumbs \(thumbArray)")
                }
                




     }catch let error {
                    print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using compactmap to remove all nil value or using map if you want to replace nil value:

```
   let thumArray = gallery.compactMap({ return $0.thumb })
   let thumArray = gallery.map({ return $0.thumb ?? ""})
```

Comment: Nitpicking but maybe you should use "replace" rather than "skip"